# Writing Pandas dataframe to Snowflake but issue with Date column

Tags: python, pandas, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've a Pandas dataframe with a date column (E.g., 29-11-2019). But when I'm writing the dataframe to Snowflake it's throwing an error like this:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 100040 (22007): Date '29-11-2019' is not recognized
```

I've tried changing the datatype to datetime:

```
df['REPORTDATE'] = df['REPORTDATE'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

and I get this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 100035 (22007): Timestamp '00:24.3' is not recognized
```

Will appreciate your help.

Comment: try `df['REPORTDATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['REPORTDATE'])`

Comment: I'm getting same error :
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 100035 (22007): Timestamp '00:24.3' is not recognized

Comment: maybe needs to be in a specific format like `df['REPORTDATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['REPORTDATE']).strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")`

Comment: maybe you want to check [this](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#label-python-connector-binding-timestmamp-qmark) out

Comment: sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 100040 (22007): Date '29/11/2019' is not recognized

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake is now enforcing strict date format and the date is expected as `YYYY-MM-DD` . Any other format is not going to be recognized and also "odd" dates like `0000-00-00` are not going to be recognized.

You can try to change the DATE_INPUT_FORMAT in session to `'dd-MM-YYYY'` and see if that fixes anything. Otherwise you'd have to re-format your sorce data (my guess would be strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")) if there is the hour/minute/second piece in it, but be aware that in DATE format for Snowflake these are getting truncated anyway.